# Why looping directly through the list/array doesn't work for linear search but works when the condition is by range

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to do a simple linear search through an array/list by asking user for a input then use a 'for loop' to compare return the index.

The loop in the code below works!

```
names = ['jon', 'eren', 'maria', 'colt']

keyword = input("enter to search in names ")

for n in range(0, len(names)):
    if keyword == names[n]:
        print(n)
```

but when I replace the first line of the loop (btw whats it called?)

```
for n in names:
    if keyword == names[n]:
        print(n)
```

It throws a error on the if statement line

*TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*

Why is that?  How is that different?

Comment: "Why is that? How is that different?" have you done *anything* to debug this? What do you think `n` is? Did you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists indexing only works for integers. This list contains values as **strings**

```
names = ['jon', 'eren', 'maria', 'colt']
```

When you iterate over the list:

```
for i in range(len(names)): #==== This is actually for i in range(4) as len(x)=4
    if names[i]==keyword:
```

You iterate over the integers, as `range` gives integers.
So it basically does:

```
names[0]
names[1]
names[2]
names[3]
```

This is valid in python.

But when you do

```
for i in names: #==== This is iterating over the list elements
    if names[i]==keyword:
```

It becomes

```
names['jon']
names['eren']
names['maria']
names['colt']
```

Python doesn't recognize this and throws a `TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing the following:

```py
for n in names:
    if keyword == names[n]:
        print(n)
```

names[n] becomes: names[jon], names[eren], and so on. That's why it doesn't work.

You should do:

```py
for n in names:
    if keyword == n:
        print(n)
```

You can also simplify it by doing:

```py
if keyword in names:
    print("Input name is in the list")
```